apt/synaptic cannot access internet on Devuan Daedalus, other tools work fine
I am on Devuan Daedalus using internet via WiFi router.
I can access internet on a browser, regularly download using yt-dlp and install/upgrade using pipx in the terminal. But when I install/update/upgrade packages using apt or synaptic, that doesn't work.
Seems very wierd, but why can't  apt or synaptic access internet?
Can someone help?
Any other info needed?
~$ ping www.duckduckgo.com
PING duckduckgo.com (20.204.244.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 20.204.244.192 (20.204.244.192): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=159 ms
64 bytes from 20.204.244.192 (20.204.244.192): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=41.2 ms
64 bytes from 20.204.244.192 (20.204.244.192): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=49.6 ms
64 bytes from 20.204.244.192 (20.204.244.192): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=40.6 ms
64 bytes from 20.204.244.192 (20.204.244.192): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=44.9 ms
64 bytes from 20.204.244.192 (20.204.244.192): icmp_seq=6 ttl=115 time=41.5 ms
^C
--- duckduckgo.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.573/62.843/159.275/43.234 ms

1 Here's my sources.list
###############
# local repos #
###############
deb [trusted=yes] file:///home/vrgovinda/offline-backup/daedalus-deb-files/ ./
deb [trusted=yes] file:///media/devuan-dvd-1/ daedalus main non-free contrib non-free-firmware

##################
# standard repos #
##################
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

2 The result of nslookup
~$ nslookup deb.devuan.org
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
deb.devuan.org  canonical name = deb.rr.devuan.org.
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 195.85.215.180
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 125.228.189.120
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 46.4.50.2
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 106.178.112.231
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 131.188.12.211
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 147.78.194.22
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 130.225.254.116
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 95.216.15.86
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 202.61.197.17
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 5.161.180.234
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 103.146.168.12
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 67.219.104.166
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 198.58.118.8
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 160.16.137.156
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 185.183.113.131
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 200.236.31.1
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 94.16.114.15
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 141.84.43.19
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 185.178.192.43
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 185.236.240.103
Name:   deb.rr.devuan.org
Address: 190.64.49.124
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
;; ERROR: ID mismatch: expected ID 48572, got 6849

~$ 

3 No there is no proxy.
4 Error message
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/daedalus/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/daedalus-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/daedalus-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'

5 Other details
$ grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf 
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

$ getent hosts deb.devuan.org
<The cursor just blinks continuously.And returns back to the prompt after a minute>

~$ apt-config dump  | grep -i proxy
~$ 


Temporary failure resolving... indicates a DNS issue. nslookup will always read /etc/resolv.conf and use the first DNS server listed there... but are you actually using /etc/resolv.conf for applications' hostname resolution? What is the output of grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf? If you run getent hosts deb.devuan.org, what is the output?

write the output of apt-config dump  | grep -i proxy # lists the proxy settings maybe apt is using a proxy

@Amirreza please check the last edit. It seems there is no proxy as I had mentioned before. This entire scenario is quite puzzling for me.

Note that nslookup always just read /etc/resolv.conf, while ping and apt could end up using APIs that leads to a different DNS server. Do you get similar error if you ping deb.devuan.org? And what's the output of resolvectl?

ping deb.devuan.org
ping: deb.devuan.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
~$
@TomYan

I'm afraid that resolvectl is not available in my system.(Devuan - systemd-free OS)

There was a problem in accessing deb.devuan.org. (I don't know the details; someone said that it has to do with round robin servers)
When I changed the mirror to  http://dev1.ipacct.in/, everything worked fine.
Thank you all for your inputs! Learnt a few things from your comments and answers ...
Regards.

First thing to catch attention is your nslookup:

~$ nslookup deb.devuan.org
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

that 192.168.0.1 is not a global IP address and is typically only found inside your home/lab/enterprise network.
There is a graphical flowchart ot help resolve “bad IP being given to you.
More details on to determine which of the five ways that your /etc/resolv.conf can be properly set.
https://tailscale.com/blog/sisyphean-dns-client-linux

Is this a well known graph, done with *nix graphing tools (nroff, ditroff, etc)? Would love to see the "source" file.

It has been recreated pretty faithfully, over and over.  Is a common classroom assignment for dotgraph.  https://github.com/egberts/dotgraphs/blob/master/README.md

Thanks very much! (forgot to include graphviz in my list). Excellent!
